# Why appear $i$ in the generator for Stone's theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis

I read the Stone's theorem for a uniparameter family of unitary operators its generator is self adjoint. I just want to know please:
Why does the complex number $i$ appear in the expression for the generator of the family $U(\tau)$ with $\tau\geq 0$,
$Ax=\lim_{\tau\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{i}\frac{(U(\tau)-I)x}{\tau}$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because the derivative of $e^{iAt}$ is $iA$.

Comment: Thank you @Martin Argerami  But is wrong if i do not put the $i$. Sorry i still not understand

Comment: $iA$ is not selfadjoint.

Comment: $\langle iAx,y\rangle=\langle x,-iAy\rangle$ right? Thank you so much

Comment: If $A$ is selfadjoint, yes.